# how to drop the str "Pandas" and the key name in the tuple when using to_csv?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like the below, and I get the df by using DataFrame.itertuples() function

```
    columnName                   
0   (CJ, 2, 1.0, 31, 34.46)
1   (CJ, 2, 1.0, 31, 34.46)
2   (CJ, 2, 1.0, 31, 34.46)
```

when I use the to_csv() function, I get the csv file like this:

```
   columnName
0  Pandas(Index='CJ', position=2, pos_options=1.0, salary=31, Value=34.46)
1  Pandas(Index='CJ', position=2, pos_options=1.0, salary=31, Value=34.46)
2  Pandas(Index='CJ', position=2, pos_options=1.0, salary=31, Value=34.46)
```

how can I dorp the annoying "Pandas" ,"index=","position=", "pos_options=","salary=", "Value="？  They are filled with the csv table and affect the human reading.

what I want is the simple expressions like this:

```
    columnName                   
0   CJ, 2, 1.0, 31, 34.46
1   CJ, 2, 1.0, 31, 34.46
2   CJ, 2, 1.0, 31, 34.46
```

Comment: How do you get this df by `DataFrame.itertuples()`? Why not just using original df?

Comment: I am working on a Basketball player prediction project,  every cell is a player data , and there are five columns means five players in game .  I am sorry to only type one column so that maybe confused you.

Comment: Maybe `reset_index()` on your original df and export that to csv is what you want? NOTE that `reset_index()` is not inplace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strip()` method:

```
df['columnName']=df['columnName'].astype(str).str.strip('()')
```

Now if you print `df` you will get:

```
    columnName
0   'CJ', 2, 1.0, 31, 34.46
1   'CJ', 2, 1.0, 31, 34.46
2   'CJ', 2, 1.0, 31, 34.46
```

**EDIT:** If you have many columns then use `apply()` method:

```
df=df.apply(lambda x:x.astype(str).str.strip('()'),1)
```

Finally use `to_csv()` method

```
df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

Comment: if there are some columns , every columns need to do so.
i do this, but it doesn't work, 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
df=df.astype(str).str.strip('()')
many thanks for your answer

Comment: you can do this if you want to change the type of whole dataframe...I used it for Series columnName as per your given dataframe in your question

Comment: For that I edited my answer kindly have a look **:)**